# Group By with Count Function Unclear

Tags: sql, postgresql, relation

I have in my DB the following relation:

```
subscribes(cid,title,publisher,offer,period)
```

It describes the subscribers to magazines ("title"), with the primary key "cid" - customer id. The other relations here are not relevant.

This is the code I run, the find all the customers (cid) that have a subscription to only one magazine:

```
select count(cid), cid 
from subscribes as r1   
group by cid 
having count(cid)=1;
```

**The question**

How do I find that one magazine, that these customers are subscribed to?

I tried just adding the "title" column to the code, and it gave me all the titles, with a $1$ on the left column of count.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: what is your rdbms? Oracle, Postgres?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza postgresql.

Comment: As @ShireResident say. use `select  cid, max(title), count(cid)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you, can you please explain why that works? supposed I had a count of 2, what would I do?

Comment: @Alan that work because you want `count = 1`  so `MAX()`  will return just that one. If you have two magazine would need a different query because you will repeat `(cid,title)`

Comment: It would have strange results.  It's a shortcut to having to do an inner select like `Akshey Bhat`'s answer.

Comment: Yes, is a shortcut to solve your original question. If you need something more generic `Akshey Bhat` is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT title, 
       cid 
FROM   subscribes 
WHERE  cid IN (SELECT cid 
               FROM   subscribes 
               GROUP  BY cid 
               HAVING Count(cid) = 1);
```

Use this query